# How can I get the result of histogram after calculation?

Tags: .net, opencv, histogram, emgucv

I found this C# code snippet for calculating a histogram:

```
    int hBins = 180;
    RangeF hRange = new RangeF(0f, 179f);       //hue's range
    int sBins = 256;
    RangeF sRange = new RangeF(0f, 255f);
    Image<Bgr, Byte> imageSource = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(originalImage.ToBitmap());
    Image<Hsv, Byte> imageHsv = imageSource.Convert<Hsv, Byte>();
    Image<Gray, Byte>[] imagesHsv = imageSource.Split();
    DenseHistogram hist = new DenseHistogram(new int[] { hBins, sBins }, new RangeF[] { hRange, sRange });
    hist.Calculate(new IImage[] { imagesHsv[0], imagesHsv[1], imagesHsv[2] }, false, null);
```

My question is: how can I get the result of histogram, as I need to get the number of the pixels for each bin)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get()` function to get specific binary values from the 2D Histogram.

```
double value = hist.get(idx1, idx2);
```

Refer to the following page for more details:
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/9ed33093-215d-93f1-7141-0b701bfa9112.htm